# Wind effect algorithm

Tags: language-agnostic

Is there any generic algorithm for wind effect?

Comment: You might get more specific help over at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I made a blog post about animating fur with a wind effect here http://martindevans.appspot.com/blog/perma?agxtYXJ0aW5kZXZhbnNyDwsSCEJsb2dQb3N0GOFdDA

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're asking how to make a realistic wind simulation. You could try a 1D noise generator like perlin or simplex noise for the wind force and direction, playing with different frequencies (fast for force and slow for direction.) I'm sure it will make the trick.